next js routing issues 404
i have a Next Js 14 app, the issue is before making the project live i had to change the routing names inside the pages/ so example: instead of Charts i did charts and same changes to the other pages, now after making the project live and accessing the "charts" page, it shows 404 not found but directly accessing the "Charts" works just fine. Should i revert the changes or anything related to caching ?
all i can find is the redirect the page to a specific route.

In conventional NextJS applications, pages are named according to folder/file structure. So, if you have /Chart, your website would be like http://your-website/Chart, but the problem is- in our web convention, we prefer pages with kebab case as this-is-a-kebab-case-word. Users and websites will always prefer /chart, so it'd be like http://your-website/chart. I'd recommend you to make sure all of your pages have lowercases and components have sentence cases.
TL;DR

Page - http://your-website/chart (Chart.js/.ts)
Component - Chart.jsx/.tsx

And if you still have 404 error, re-routing is the solution. Fix the route names and then build the whole application.

yeah according to the naming convention i changes it to charts but when made the project live the charts.jsx was not working but directly accessing the http://your-website/Charts was working instead

Cache trouble, clear the cache maybe.
